# Antenna: RF, need help

Tags: rf, antenna, model, loss

I am trying to find a path loss model for "wireless sensor network". More specifically, I am looking for model for Cellular tower  100~1000MHz) and (60~600W) as transmitter and a small wireless sensor node as the receiver(most likely to be placed on ground level).

Then I come across on a model which is  only applicable to "

The resulting path loss model applies to **base antenna** heights from 10 to 80 m, base-to-terminal distances from 0.1 to 8 km, and three distinct terrain categories.
"

My question is: what is the **base antenna? (Does it mean the transmitter base station antenna only or also the receiver antenna as well?** Do you guys think this model will satisfy the aforemention requirement?

Comment: Any Help: http://www.utdallas.edu/~torlak/courses/ee4367/lectures/lectureradio.pdf and http://users.ece.gatech.edu/stuber/6604/2013-lectures/week8.pdf (this last one covers the Okumura Hata model which I believe is quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you came across an okumura hata (OH) propagation model
Base antenna is height of the antenna converted into ideal isotropic and it should inlcude the height where it will be installed.

OH model is an empirical model, meaning it will work properly if it used inside the model boundaries and you can squeeze 3 sigma standard deviation conformance at best.

however, however how low in the ground does your wireless sensor lie? OH model is bounded by 1 meter height until you encounter fading due to low aperture angles. Your three (3) morphology models may not work properly (terrain categories).

here are the links of the model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okumura_model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hata_model_for_urban_areas